# laravel route return route gives not defined error

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to learn some laravel and I came across the following code:

```
Route::get('/blob1', function(){
        return route('create');
});
```

If I type localhost/site/blob1  I get a "route create not defined" I tried the following bit of code and also tried  /blob1/create but get the same error - have I misunderstood the route returning a route syntax??

```
Route::get('/create', function(){
        return route('create');
});
```

Comment: I think you sould look laravel docs first. You are making basic mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route::get('/blob1', function(){
    return redirect()->route('create');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your route

```
Route::get('/create', function(){
    return route('create');
});
```

add new route

```
Route::get('/create', [
    'as' => 'create',
    'uses' => 'TestController@index'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers so when would you use a route to a route and why??

Comment: Try to route or redirect from controller is a best option as a developer...as if u define a redirect route in your route file...d'not look good according to coding standards..so according to me its good to use redirect function in your controller...